# Reload data after fetch link modification

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to create a pagination.

I have a function called `LoadList`, this loads items from an external API asyc. Another function called `next()` changes the API link offset value on every click. This is all right but I don't know how to solve to refresh the content of the fetched list.
My goal is to populate the table based on JSON data depending the offset value from the `next()` function.

The table is populated, with the first 20 items. Then if I click a button I want to add the second 20 and so on. I have the first 20 (`https:// .../pokemon?offset=0&limit=20`) items. When I click the button the URL changes (`https:// .../pokemon?offset=20&limit=20`) this means the next 20 items. The problem is that I don't know how to refresh the list after the URL changes.

```js
    async function loadList() {
    showLoadingMessage();
    try {
      const response = await fetch(next());
      console.log(response);
      const json = await response.json();
    json.results.forEach(function(item) {
    const itemNameCapitalized = item.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + item.name.slice(1);
    let pokemon = {
      name: itemNameCapitalized,
      detailsUrl: item.url
    };
add(pokemon);

      function next() {
    if(offset < totalItems){
      apiUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=' + offset + '&limit=20';
      console.log(apiUrl);
      offset = offset + 20;
      return apiUrl;
    } else {
      offset = 1120;
    }
  }



 function add(pokemon) {
    if (typeof pokemon === 'object' &&
      'name' in pokemon &&
      'detailsUrl' in pokemon
    ) {
      pokemonList.push(pokemon);
    } else {
      console.log(`The Pokemon is not correct!<br>`);
    }
  }
```

as you can see the link updates correctly:

[image: link is changing]

Comment: What are you doing with `json`?

Comment: Please don't put lenghty bits of code in comments. Edit your question instead. Also, it sounds like your issue is rather with populating a table based on API data and less with the pagination/fetch? Please clarify what the exact issue is.

Comment: Ok, so how are you populating the table the first time?

Comment: Note that as far as I can tell, your question is "how can I create table content based on an array?" That has nothing to do with offsets, pagination or fetch and is a very common question with lots of existing answers.

Comment: The table is populated, I just want to add 20 items, not all of them. Then if I click a button I want to add the second 20 and so on. I have the first 20(https:// .../pokemon?offset=0&limit=20) items. When I click the button the url changes (https:// .../pokemon?offset=20&limit=20) this means the next 20 items. The problem is that idk how to refresh the list after the url changes.

Comment: I get all that. What exactly is `add(pokemon);` doing? Is it appending a table row to the existing table? If yes, it should already work fine. If not, show the function's code and describe how exactly it fails.

Comment: yes, it`s appending a row to the table.

Comment: AGAIN: what doesn't work? Here's a working example using your code: https://jsfiddle.net/2nwrfzbj/ what do you mean by "refresh the list"?

Comment: yes, that is what I want with that little difference that I need to remove the first 20 when I load the second 20.

Comment: So you're basically asking how to remove all rows from a table? Also, you said `Then if I click a button I want to add the second 20 and so on`, emphasis on **add**

Comment: yes, I`m basically asking how to remove the value of the 20 rows and add another values.

Comment: Just set the <tbody>'s `innerHTML = ""` before your forEach loop.